# Access --- repeat an ID that does not duplicate

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a database that I populate through VBA/Excel.
My main field is `TRADE_ID` that is set as no duplicates.
I have some trades that reset every month for some times...3 month for this example
So my field TRADE_ID  will look like

```
ABCDEFGH-1   'for 1st month
ABCDEFGH-2   'for 2nd month
ABCDEFGH-3   'for 3rd month
```

When my trade is closed... I want to forbid `ABCDEFGH` as the beginning as an `TRADE_ID`

I dont know how it can be possible

---

Here is the code i use to generate ID

```
For Each cl In Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
 If cl.Offset(0, -2).Value = "NEW" or cl.Offset(0, -2).Value = "RESET"Then
    If cl.Value <> currentvalue Then
        currentinteger = 1
        currentvalue = cl.Value
    Else
        currentinteger = currentinteger + 1
    End If
     cl.Offset(0, -1).Value = "OPT-" & Year(Date) & Format(Month(Date), "00") & Format(Day(Date), "00") & "-" & Format(cl.Value, "0000") & "-" & Chr(64 + currentinteger) & cl.Offset(0, 1).Value
   End If
  Next cl
```

So basically if `If cl.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLOSE"`

i want to forbid `"OPT-" & Year(Date) & Format(Month(Date), "00") & Format(Day(Date), "00") & "-" & Format(cl.Value, "0000") & "-" & Chr(64 + currentinteger`  as the beginning of an ID int the database

Comment: How, exactly, are you creating this ID?  Can you post the code?  My first instinct is that it's going to have something to do with using the InStr() and Left() functions, but I can give you something more specific when I see how the ID is generated.

Comment: Just updated the subject

Answer (score 0):

It should work to split the key into 2 fields - "ABCDEFGH" as the primary key in one table, and a 2nd transaction table with 2 key fields, one "ABCDEFGH" and the 2nd field "1", "2", "3", etc.  The 1st table would hold any data common to all the transaction for ABCDEFGH and the 2nd table would have the unique data for each transaction.

When you try to add the next trade, the unique key in the 1st table would prevent the re-use of the ABCDEFGH as a key.  The use of two keys on the 2nd table would prevent the re-use of ABCDEFGH-2, for example.

I don't normally set up relationships and enforce referential integrity, but depending on what you need you could look into those two topics to enforce consistency between the two tables.